# Is this the correct way to use the word 'persuade' and 'predefined'?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-meaning

"You can use the word 'that's at the end of the sentence only if its persuaded by predefined context"

Is it right how I used the word 'persuade' and 'predefined' in this sentence. If no please ascertain the correct words.

Comment: I think you mean ***preceded***??

Comment: I would use neither "persuade" nor "prededined" in this way.

Comment: Then kindly correct the sentence

Comment: How are we going to correct the sentence when we don't know what it's supposed to mean?

Comment: Do you mean "You can use the word 'that' at the end of a sentence only if it's preceded by its meaning"? Or "... only if it's defined by its context"? Or something else?

Answer (score 1):

1. *persuaded* should be *preceded*.
2. *predefined context* doesn't make sense here. Deleting *predefined*.
3. It's common to confuse *it's* and *its*. You want *it's*, or simply write it out as *it is*.

> You can use the word only if it is preceded by context.

Answer (score 0):

> "You can use the word 'that's at the end of the sentence only if its persuaded by predefined context"

There are several mistakes in the example above, as identified in the comments and the earlier reply.

We could say

> "You could use the pronoun *that* in later part of a sentence only if it has been identified earlier by an antecedent."

This is to ensure pronoun-antecedent rule is observed.